# Python os.system: извлечение архивов с паролями

Tags: python, архивация

Есть строка, которая извлекает файлы из архивов:

```
os.system(rf'D:\Programs\7-Zip\7z.exe x {путь к файлу} -o{папка куда извлекаем} -p{пароль}')
```

Так вот, "пароль" берется из словаря с помощью `for` и подставляется сюда.

Также все это завернуто в `try` на случай, если пароль не подойдёт, то повторить уже с другим паролем, а если пароль подойдёт, то `break`.

Но вот `try`, видимо, не ловит ошибки из `os.system` и перебирает дальше пароли, если даже он подошёл. И, получается, что когда пароль подходит, файлы извлекаются из архива, он дальше пробует другой пароль, и он, естественно, не подходит, но все равно извлекает уже файлы с 0 байтом (размером) и просит меня перезаписать те файлы.

Приходит сообщение вида "нажмите Y, если хотите перезаписать файл". Ну, и другие там N, Q и т.д. Как это исправить?

Comment: Проверяйте на возвращаемое значение `os.system`. А флаг `-y`. ``os.system(rf'D:\Programs\7-Zip\7z.exe x {путь к файлу} -o{папка куда извлекаем} -p{пароль} -y')``

Comment: Если вдруг архивы `zip`, можно попробовать библиотечный `zipfile` использовать. А если `7z`, то можно использовать `subprocess.check_call`, он как раз вызывает исключение при ненулевом коде возврата.